# Teechart red cross error - C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Scenario:

I have a windows forms application that opens another form when pressing a button.  This opened form contains a teechart.  I haven't programmed too much into it because I noticed that when I close the form, with the teechart, and then reopen it there is a big red "X" across it.  A few things that I have done:  I cancel the closing event to prevent any data from the object being lost. I also hide the form.  When I run in debug mode, I do not get any exceptions that happen so it's difficult for me to pinpoint what is going.

So, I run the executable outside the IDE and when forcing the scenario I get this error that pops up:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc()
   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics.Render(Graphics target)
   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics.Render()
   at Steema.TeeChart.TChart.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here and how to better visualize this?

Comment: Presumably something in the TeeChart control is being disposed in response to the Closing event, and this is causing the exception when the form is shown the second time.  You might need to let the form close normally and recreate it.  Have you contacted support for the TeeChart control?

Comment: I am using the form to display information given from the parent form.  If I close the form the data transferred will be lost. If I closed the form properly doesn't that dispose the form object?

Comment: Whether the form is disposed or not depends on whether it's modal or an MDI child window.  Refer to the Form.Close method documentation on MSDN for examples.  Technically since you're canceling the FormClose event, nothing should be getting disposed - but the TeeChart control might not be following standard conventions since it's a 3rd-party control.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by modal, but it is not an MDI.  To correct I am cancelling the Form.FormClosing event.